# off() / on() VS stopImmediatePropagation best practices

Tags: jquery, ajax

I had a problem with a little ajax app where a lot of element are added / deleted dynamically.
I found that my ajax calls were done multiple times, because I thought that using On() would replace the current event instead of just adding it the function.

So i started using off() every time i needed an event. It's horrible.
I just discovered stopImmediatePropagation() and it seems that it has the same effect, but better performance and readability.

I saw a lot of tutorials, but there are a lot of old / removed things.

I'm looking for a way to do the best practices in using events with jQuery.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `$(container).on('event', 'selector', function() {...});` version of `on()`?

Comment: @JasonP
Yes, always. I already had problems with selecting directly the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use event delegation in this case. Normally when you bind an event in jQuery you're binding it to specific elements, but if you know elements are going to be added in during run time (via ajax etc.) you can use event delegation; event delegation runs the selector when the event is fired, rather then bind-time.

When you bind your event simply set the selector, so for example,

```
$(window).on('click', 'button.fun', function() {
    alert('how fun');
});
```

In the above code, any time you click on button.fun an alert will pop up with the text how fun. These buttons be can added/removed freely. Do note though that you shouldn't directly bind to `window` unless you need to; the more specific the container the better.

`stopImmediatePropagation` is merely saying to stop dispatching the event, however, all the events are still bound so it's wasteful of memory etc.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to define your events for all the tags where they are applicable and nowhere else. For this purpose you should use a selector as specific as possible which still defines all the tags where the event should be active. If more tags should share the same event or the same style, then they can have common CSS classes.